# Why are there no more images revealed by New Horizon?

Tags: pluto

Since a few days after the flyby there are no more images published on the NASA page.

Why is NASA waiting to publish any more images for some reason?

Or is there something happened to New Horizon?

Comment: I know they said that its going to take something like 16 months to receive all data http://gizmodo.com/why-itll-take-new-horizons-16-months-to-send-us-this-we-1717769317

Comment: I asked essentially [the same question](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/10655/574) on the [Space Exploration site](http://space.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2015/06240556-what-to-expect-new-horizons-pluto.html

> The transmission of the High Priority data set will be complete on July 20, and then image transmission will pause. For nearly two months, until September 14, New Horizons will switch to near-real-time downlinking of data from other, so-called "low-speed" instruments while it transmits just housekeeping information for all of the rest of the data. No new images will arrive on the ground during this time